# Is it possible to replace git merge algorithm?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I'm wondering if it is possible to write my own custom merger and use it in place of the standard one.

The only idea that comes to mind is to put it into config as merge.tool, but that will make it run AFTER the standard git-merge, not instead of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read gitattributes [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html):

> Defining a custom merge driver
>
> The definition of a merge driver is done in the .git/config file, not in the gitattributes file, so strictly speaking this manual page is a wrong place to talk about it. However…
>
> To define a custom merge driver filfre, add a section to your $GIT_DIR/config file (or $HOME/.gitconfig file) like this:

```
[merge "filfre"]
    name = feel-free merge driver
    driver = filfre %O %A %B
    recursive = binary
```